# Complex and real roots of a polynomial

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, solution-verification, proof-explanation, roots

The question I've attempted is;

i)    - Let $\beta$ be a root of the complex monic polynomial $P(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1z+a_0$. $M$ is the maximum of $|a_{n-1}|,|a_{n-2}|...|a_0|$. Show that $|\beta|<M+1$

ii)- Let $S(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{c_k(x+\frac1x)^n}$, where the real numbers $c_k$ satisfy $|c_k|≤|c_n|$ for all $k<n$, and $c_n≠0$, using part i) show that $S(x)$ has no real solutions.

I've done part i) like this which I think is right;

$P(\beta)=\beta^n+a_{n-1}\beta^{n-1}+...+a_1\beta+a_0=0$
$\beta^n=-(a_{n-1}\beta^{n-1}+...+a_1\beta+a_0)$
$|\beta|^n=|a_{n-1}\beta^{n-1}+...+a_1\beta+a_0|$
$|\beta|^n≤|a_{n-1}||\beta^{n-1}|+...+|a_1||\beta|+|a_0|$ by extended triangle inequality
$|\beta|^n≤M|\beta^{n-1}|+...+M|\beta|+M$ $\because$ $M≥|a_{n-1}|,|a_{n-2}|...|a_0|$
$|\beta|^n≤M(|\beta^{n-1}|+...+|\beta|+1)$
$|\beta|^n≤M(\frac{|\beta|^n-1}{|\beta|-1})$
$|\beta|^n(|\beta|-1)≤M(|\beta|^n-1)$
$|\beta|-1≤M-\frac1{|\beta|^n}$
$|\beta|-1<M$ $\because$ $\frac1{|\beta|^n}>0$
$|\beta|<M+1$ as required

Can someone also check part ii)

Let $\beta$ be a real root of $S(x)$ 
Consider $\frac{S(\beta)}{c_n}=0$
$\frac{c_0}{c_n}(\beta+\frac1\beta)^0+\frac{c_1}{c_n}(\beta+\frac1\beta)^1+...+\frac{c_n-1}{c_n}(\beta+\frac1\beta)^{n-1}+\frac{c_n}{c_n}(\beta+\frac1\beta)^n=0$
From part i) where $M=|\frac{c_k}{c_n}|$,  $|\beta+\frac1\beta|≤|\frac{c_k}{c_n}|+1$
$|\beta+\frac1\beta|<2\because|\frac{c_k}{c_n}|≤1$
However, consider $|\beta+\frac1\beta|≥2$
$LHS-RHS=|\beta|+\frac{1}{|\beta|}-2$
=$\frac{|\beta|^2-2|\beta|+1}{|\beta|}$
=$\frac{(|\beta|-1)^2}{|\beta|}$
$≥0$
$\therefore LHS≥RHS$
Therefore $\beta$ cannot be a root as if it was a root $\beta+\frac1\beta<2$ and $\beta+\frac1\beta≥2$.  
$\therefore$ $S(x)$ has no real roots since $\frac{S(x)}{c_n}=0$ has no real solutions

Comment: Estimate $\lvert \beta + \beta^{-1} \rvert$ for a root $\beta$. What values does $x+x^{-1}$ take on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I guess $x+x^{-1}>1$ when $x>0$, I'm not sure how that helps

Comment: Plot $x + x^{-1}$ and see if you can get more useful bounds.

Comment: Desmos showed $x+x^-1≥2$ and I've edited the question with a new proof, could you just check if it's watertight?

Comment: You should have $\left| \beta + \frac1\beta \right|<2$ (note this is strictly less than) using part (i), which will then contradict with $\left| \beta +\frac1\beta \right| \geqslant 2$ for reals.